# 写日记 or 写日记本 ? Which is more colloquial?

Tags: vocabulary

Which of the versions listed above is better to use.

My understanding is that they are essentially the same but I'd like to hear from a native speaker how they feel about these two versions.

Is there any subtle difference ?

Let's say the complete sentence is: 我每天写日记(本)。

To 本 or not to 本 , that is the question.

Answer (score 3):

写日记本 is a wrong phrase. It should be 往日记本上写 or 写在日记本上.

写日记 is a common term to mean *write a diary*

Answer (score 2):

日记 = Diary; 本 = book. 寫(记)日记 is an activity, and 日记本 is a notepad that collects that activity over time.

- A **diary (日记)** is a collection of daily activities/thoughts written down on a **diary book (日记本)**.
- A **diary book (日记本)** is a notepad for a person to write his/her **diary (日记)**.
- My **diary (日记)** is kept on (记在) that blue **diary book (日记本)**.

I hope you see the differences.

Answer (score -1):

写日记 "write diary" is more idiomatic. The word "diary" here refers to the thought and memories you put on paper, aka "diary entries"

"写(日记在)日记本" = "write (dairy) on diary book" sounds clumsy

日记本 is the physical notebook that you write your 日记 (dairy ) on